# Рефлексия. Доступ к полям объекта неизвестного класса

Tags: c#, рефлексия

У меня возникла весьма специфическая задача. Нужно получить доступ к полям объекта, клас которого мне не известен.

**Например:**

Имеется класс А, о котором мы знаем только имя некоторого его поля ("field"):

```
public class A
{
    string field;

    public A(string name)
    {
        field = name;
    }
}
```

Код который нам известен:

```
// a - сюда будет передан объект класса А, но мы, естественно, этого не знаем.
// name - название некоторого поля объекта а
public string Foo(object a, string name)
{
    //тут мы получаем доступ с помощью рефлексии
    return *значение поля с именем name объекта a*
}
```

Из какого то места программы будет вызван данный метод.

```
Console.WriteLine(
    Foo(new A("text"), "field")
);
```

Каким образом я могу получить доступ к полю объекта, приведенного к типу `object`? И возможно ли то вообще?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static string Foo(object a, string name)
{
    var field = a.GetType().GetField(name, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var value = field.GetValue(a);
    return value.ToString();
}
```

`a.GetType()` возвращает настоящий тип объекта (`A`), поэтому просто вызываем `GetField()`.

`BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance` говорят о том, что мы хотим получить непубличное экземплярное поле.

`field.GetValue(a)` возвращает значение поля.

Answer (score 3):

Например так

```
object GetFieldValue(object src, string fieldName)
{
    return src?.GetType().GetFields().Where(f=>f.Name == fieldName).Select(f=>f.GetValue(src)).FirstOrDefault();    
}
```

Допустим у нас есть класс

```
class MyClass
{
    public int Field1;
    public string Field2;
}
```

Тогда

```
var ob = new MyClass() {Field1 = 10, Field2 = "bla bla bla"};
Console.WriteLine(GetFieldValue(ob, nameof(MyClass.Field1)));
Console.WriteLine(GetFieldValue(ob, nameof(MyClass.Field2)));
```

Выведет

```
10
bla bla bla
```